# curl on django staging server(EC2) redirects to localhost

Tags: python, django, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

Command -

```
curl -I http://stage.servername.com/
```

Response -

```
HTTP/1.1 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 02 Dec 2014 13:18:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
x-frame-options: DENY
Location: https://127.0.0.1:8000/
x-content-type-options: nosniff
P3P: CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"
```

Following is my nginx setting - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f84c5b7bed41b40a3cfd

The gunicorn server is running at port 8000.

```
(bz)username@ip-172-31-4-167:~$ ps aux|grep gunicorn
username    2283  0.0  0.5  51912 11028 ?        S    11:42   0:00 /home/username/Envs/bz/bin/python /home/username/Envs/bz/bin/gunicorn bizchat.wsgi:application --workers=3 -D
username    2288  0.0  1.3 136244 28428 ?        S    11:42   0:00 /home/username/Envs/bz/bin/python /home/username/Envs/bz/bin/gunicorn bizchat.wsgi:application --workers=3 -D
username    2289  0.0  1.3 136260 28428 ?        S    11:42   0:00 /home/username/Envs/bz/bin/python /home/username/Envs/bz/bin/gunicorn bizchat.wsgi:application --workers=3 -D
username    2290  0.0  1.7 144484 36860 ?        S    11:42   0:00 /home/username/Envs/bz/bin/python /home/username/Envs/bz/bin/gunicorn bizchat.wsgi:application --workers=3 -D
username    3452  0.0  0.0  10468   924 pts/0    S+   13:09   0:00 grep --color=auto gunicorn
```

nginx service is ok.

I am however using [django-secure](http://django-secure.readthedocs.org/) but with the following flag `SSLIFY_DISABLE=True`

When I open the **url.myapp.com** it `redirects` to `https://127.0.0.1:8000`

Any idea, what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your nginx.conf if you don't have it:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```